# Работа Танка в режиме Distributed Testing

Tags: яндекс-танк

Может ли *Танк* работать в режиме Distributed Testing, то есть руководить большим количеством стреляющих клиентов? А главное - консолидированно собирать информацию со всех машин и представлять её в виде единого отчета и т.п.?

Answer (score 3):

Сам танк нет, но есть https://github.com/yandex-load/yandex-tank-api, консолидированный единый отчет оно правда не создает.